# Retrieving data from listview when im using adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am able to display the toast in my menuactivity but now i will need to get the selected data from listview and display it on another page. I have tried alot of methods and search on it but i cant seem to get it.

menuactivity :

```
    public class MenuActivity extends Activity {


    private String server = "http://172.16.156.56";
    private String sql_table = "orders";
    private ListView list;
    private TextView txtOrder, txtMember, txtPrice;
    private Button btnAdd;
    ArrayList<String> rows;

    ListView listView1;
    Button btnSubmit;
    ArrayList<CustomItem> itemList, selectedList;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


        list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        rows = new ArrayList<String>();


        itemList=new ArrayList<CustomItem>();
        itemList.add(new CustomItem("Fried Rice","description","1","Quantity"));
        itemList.add(new CustomItem("Fried Noodle","description","2","Quantity"));
        itemList.add(new CustomItem("Prawn noodle","description","3","Quantity"));
        itemList.add(new CustomItem("Chicken Rice","description","4","Quantity"));

        int[] prgmImages={R.drawable.friedrice,R.drawable.friednoodle,R.drawable.pnoodle,R.drawable.chickenrice};

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final CustomLVAdapter customLVAdapter = new CustomLVAdapter(this, itemList,prgmImages);
        listView1.setAdapter(customLVAdapter);


        txtOrder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txtMember = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        txtPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt3);


        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                selectedList = new ArrayList<CustomItem>();
                int total = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
                    CustomItem object = itemList.get(i);
                    if (object.isSelected()) {
                        responseText.append(object.getItem() + "," + object.getQty() + ",");//item
                        selectedList.add(object);
                        //calculate price
                        total = total + Integer.parseInt(object.getQty()) * Integer.parseInt(object.getPrice());

                    }


                }
                Add(responseText.toString(), "5565", String.valueOf(total));


                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReceiptActivity.class);



                startActivity(i);




                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseText + " $" + total,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                SelectAll();
                //store in database

                //go to ReceiptActivity - membership, item, totalprice

            }
        });


    }





    public void Add(final String item, final String membership, final String price)
    {
        RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = server + "/insertorder.php";
        StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                MyData.put("item",item );
                MyData.put("membership",membership );
                MyData.put("price",price );

                return MyData;
            }
        };
        MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
        SelectAll();
    }
    public void SelectAll()
    {
        RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = server + "/fetchorder.php";
        StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray(sql_table);
                    rows.clear();
                    for(int i=0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                        String order       = jsonChildNode.optString("item").toString();
                        String membership     = jsonChildNode.optString("membership").toString();
                        String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price").toString();

                        rows.add(order + ", " + membership + ", " + price );
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MenuActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rows);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //This code is executed if there is an error.
            }
        });
        MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
    }



}
```

Receipt activity ( the page i wan to display my results)

```
public class ReceiptActivity extends Activity {
static public String txtOrder = "";
TextView foodorder;
ArrayList<CustomItem> itemList, selectedList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receipt);


    CustomLVAdapter item = (CustomLVAdapter) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    TextView foodorder = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foodorder);
    foodorder.setText("Order:" +strOrder+" ");
```

Custom adapter

```
 public class CustomLVAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<CustomItem> objectList;
    private int[] imageId;
    public static ArrayList<CustomItem> arl_food=new ArrayList<>();

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt1,txt2,txt3;
        CheckBox ckBox;
        ImageView image;

        NumberPicker np;
    }




    public CustomLVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomItem> objectList,int[]prgmImages){
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.objectList = objectList;
        this.imageId = prgmImages;


    }

    public int getCount(){
        return objectList.size();
    }

    public CustomItem getItem (int position) {
        return objectList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;


        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_checkbox_textview, null);
            holder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            holder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            holder.txt3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
            holder.image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.ckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ckBox);
            holder.np  = (NumberPicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
            holder.np.setMinValue(0);
            holder.np.setMaxValue(10);






            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.ckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                                                    CustomItem object = (CustomItem) cb.getTag();
                                                    Toast.makeText(context,
                                                            "You have selected:  " + object.getItem() +
                                                                    "Price: " + object.getPrice() +
                                                                    "Qty: " + object.getQty(),
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    object.setSelected(cb.isChecked());

                                                }
                                            }
            );

            holder.np.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                    NumberPicker p = picker;
                    CustomItem object = (CustomItem) p.getTag();
                    object.setQty(String.valueOf(newVal));

                }
            });
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        CustomItem object = objectList.get(position);
        holder.txt1.setText(object.getItem());
        holder.txt2.setText(object.getDesc());
        holder.txt3.setText(object.getPrice());

        holder.np.setTag(object);
        holder.image.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        holder.ckBox.setChecked(object.isSelected());
        holder.ckBox.setTag(object);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this line CustomLVAdapter item = (CustomLVAdapter) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);  where is the parent from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are already starting an activity when the submit button is clicked. Now all you have to do is pass a couple extras in the intent you are creating.

So when you make the intent you should also do this:

```
...
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReceiptActivity.class);
i.putExtra("PRICE", price);
i.putExtra("MEMBERSHIP", membership);
i.putExtra("ITEM", item);
startActivity(i);
...
```

Then in your new activity you will read out the extras in your onCreate method like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receipt);
    int price = getIntent().getStringExtra("PRICE");
    String membership = getIntent().getStringExtra("MEMBERSHIP");
    CustomItem item = getIntent().getStringExtra("ITEM");
    ...
```

One Caveat! It looks like you are representing your items with the object CustomItem. In order to pass that as an extra it will have to implement Parcelable. When you implement Parcelable you will define how to turn the object and its fields into a "parcel" and how to turn a "parcel" back into your object. The [google docs give a pretty good example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for it.

I lied, another caveat! I would recommend that you make the keys for the extras "public static final String"s inside of your ReceiptActivity. That way you will have an easier time managing them.

Comment: Also, one recommendation: first try passing just one piece of info between the activities. Once you get that to work do the next. Save your CustomItem object for last.